# Finding permutations using backtracking

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking

I am having trouble understanding a backtracking solution. I am new to algorithms and recursion. This is a leetcode problem. Leetcode 46.

```
class Solution:
    def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:

        results = []
        if len(nums) == 1:
            return [nums[:]]
        
        for _ in range(len(nums)):
            n = nums.pop(0)
            perms = self.permute(nums)

            for perm in perms:
                perm.append(n)
            
            results.extend(perms)
            nums.append(n)
        
        return results
```

I am struggling with the fact that when I invoke the function with nums = [2, 3], the results variable contains the values results = [[3, 2], [2, 3]]. Subsequently, when these permutations are returned and 1 is appended to them, I expected that when results.extend() is encountered, the results should become results = [[3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 2, 1], [2, 3, 1]]. Can you help me understand where I might be mistaken?"

I tried dry running the code and printing the value of variables at subsequent calls, but could not decipher the concept

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you think of `results` as a *single* variable, but that is not true: every execution of the function `permutute` has its own, local `result` list. `results.extends` only affects one of those local variables, not the variable with the same name that is local to the *caller* of the function.

When the results `[[3, 2], [2, 3]]` are returned to the caller, the caller's `result` list is still empty -- it has no connection with the `result` variable that was used to get `[[3, 2], [2, 3]]`. *That* latter `result` variable no longer exists, as it stopped being something as soon as you got back from the recursive call that returned `[[3, 2], [2, 3]]`.